# Group Categories in columnrange highcharts with custom view

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using highcharts with angular 4.

I want to create a chart to show the result something like this:

[image]

Where:

- GHRM and HR Scanner are application name.
- We are showing some data groupwise (application wise here)

To achieve the above result I have tried using columnrange chart type in highcharts.

But the result of above link differs from my requirement. As you can see the result of above link:

[image]

Can any one help me to know how I can customize the categories view in this case to achieve the result as shown in first screen shot.

Comment: Working jsfiddle URL:https://jsfiddle.net/k1dzcrbj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting that kind of look with **grouped categories** plugin would be a rather a hard task to accomplish.

Another approach is using a separate x axis for each set of categories (GHRM and HR Scanner in your case).

Axes can be positioned via `left` & `top` properties and sized via `height` properties. These options are not documented yet but they work. They accept relative values in percents (e.g. `30%`) and absolute values in pixels (e.g. `200px`).

```
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Category 1'],
    tickWidth: 0,
    height: '30%',
    offset: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'First x axis',
      rotation: 0,
      align: 'high'
    }
  }, {
    categories: ['Category 2', 'Category 3'],
    tickWidth: 0,
    height: '60%',
    top: '40%',
    offset: 0,
    title: {
      align: 'high',
      text: 'Second x axis',
      rotation: 0
    }
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      grouping: false,
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [1, 7]
    ],
  }, {
    data: [
      [2, 4],
      [3, 8]
    ],
    xAxis: 1
  }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s3k3s944/

`grouping` has to be disabled so that columns are always centered. `pointPadding`, `groupPadding` and `borederWidth` force columns to occupy maximum vertical range.

All other options of axes configuration can be found in the **Highcharts API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/

Comment: Thanks kamil kulig I will try this

Comment: I have implemented as you suggested below is my url:http://jsfiddle.net/n1sr3ye7/

Comment: As you can see in the above my solution URL text "Global software catalog" is not properly visible and align.Can you help me how this can be fixed

Comment: Probably it's caused by using unsupported properties (`width`, `height`, `top`, `left`). This demo has the code in `chart.render` event that forces axes' titles to align: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bjm7Lktn/